# Then number of ways of arranging the letters of word ALGEBRA in which either vowels or consonants but not both appear in alphabetical order

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The number of ways of arranging the letters of word ALGEBRA in which either vowels or consonants but not both appear in alphabetical order

My attempt:

Let $A$ is number of ways in which consonants are in alphabetical order i.e., $\dfrac{7!}{4!\cdot 2!}=105$.

Let $B$ is number of ways in which vowels are in alphabetical order i.e., $\dfrac{7!}{3!}=840$

Let $C$ is number of ways in which both vowels and consonants are in alphabetical order i.e., $\dfrac{7!}{4!\cdot 3!}=35$

So obtained answer by me is $105+840-35=910$

But given answer is $943$.

I want to know where am I going wrong.

Comment: $A,B,C$ seem to be computed correctly. The answer should be $A + B - 2C$; $A + B - C$ also counts arrangements where both appear in the correct order. However, this doesn't match up with the given answer either

Comment: @mcd Even if question was according to you How did you obtained $2$?

Comment: You are right. The answer given is just wrong! I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of different words we can form with the letters $A,L,G,E,B,R,A$ are $\frac{7!}{2!}$ which gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{7!}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{4!}\color{blue}{=105}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
words with consonants $\color{blue}{B,G,L,R}$ in alphabetical order and
\begin{align*}
\frac{7!}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\color{blue}{=840}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
words with vowels $\color{blue}{A,A,E}$ in alphabetical order in accordance with OPs calculation. We want to calculate the number of valid words which have either consonants or vowels but not both in alphabetical order.

> There are
> \begin{align*}
>  \frac{7!}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{4!3}\color{blue}{=35}
>  \end{align*}
> different words which have both consonants and vowels in alphabetical order. We have to subtract this number from (1) but also from (2) since these words are counted in *both* calculations.
>
> We conclude there is a total of
> \begin{align*}
> 105+840-2\cdot 35\color{blue}{=875}
> \end{align*}
> valid words in accordance with a comment of @BenGrossmann.

*Note:* I've also verified this result with a piece of R code as additional plausibility check.

Answer (score 2):

not $A+B-C$, but $A+B-C-C$ ,

$A+B-C$ counts $\#(A\cup B)$ [Union (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))

$A+B-C-C$ counts $\#(A \ominus B)$  [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#)

---

Assuming permutations here  dont' admit repeation, e.g. $A_1LGEBRA_2$ and $A_2LGEBRA_1$ just count once.

I wrote Mathematica code to **count**

```
list = Permutations[Characters@"ALGEBRA"]


list // Cases[#, {___, "A", ___, "A", ___, "E", ___}] & // 
  DeleteCases[#, {___, "B", ___, "G", ___, "L", ___, 
     "R", ___}] & // Length
(*vowels in alphabetical order,but consonants not, count 805*)


list // DeleteCases[#, {___, "A", ___, "A", ___, "E", ___}] & // 
  Cases[#, {___, "B", ___, "G", ___, "L", ___, "R", ___}] & // Length
(*consonants in alphabetical order,but vowels not, count 70*)
```

so the answer to your question is $805+70=\color{red}{875}$